# VBA- How to copy and paste values to another sheet beginning on next available row

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I have a vba code that copies rows on a sheet to another sheet depending if column A = 1 and it works perfectly. I am trying to make it paste to the next available row instead of overwriting the data that is already there in order to make a log. Here is the code I have already but I can't seem to figure out how to make it paste to the next available row. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Log()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Variant
Dim count As Long
count = 0
     With ActiveSheet

lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = .Range("A3:A" & lastRow)

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "1" Then
       Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 6)).Copy
       Range("'Log'!B3").Offset(count, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       count = count + 1
    End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you familiar with using .Cells(row#, col#) instead of Range(A1)?

Comment: `Range("'Log'!B3").Offset(count, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` is incorrect syntax. Try `Sheets("Log!B3").Range("A1").Offset(count,0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: The answer provided by @peege worked like a charm. Thank you! I'm just starting to learn programming and this helps me a lot!

Comment: That's what I was hoping.  Glad to hear it.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop through the source sheet.

Try using .Cells(row,col) instead of Range..

This example is heavy on the comments to help understand the looping process.

You will need a few additional Functions to make this work using this code.

**LastRow Function**

```
Function lastRow(sheet As String) As Long

    lastRow = Sheets(sheet).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'Using Cells()

End Function
```

**LastCol Function**

```
Function lastCol(sheet As String) As Long

    lastCol = Sheets(sheet).Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

End Function
```

**Code for solution:**  Assuming you have your target sheet's headers already set up AND the target and source sheet share the same formatting.

```
Sub Log()

Dim source As String, target As String
Dim sRow As Long, col As Long, tRow As Long

'Declare Sheets
source = "Sheet1"
target = "Sheet2"

'Loop through rows of source sheet
For sRow = 2 To lastRow(source)

    'Get current last row of Target Sheet
    tRow = lastRow(target) + 1

    'Meet criteria for Column A to = 1 on Source
    If Sheets(source).Cells(sRow, 1) = "1" Then
        'Copy each column of source sheet to target sheet in same order
        For col = 1 To lastCol(source)
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, col) = Sheets(source).Cells(sRow, col)
        Next col
    End If

Next sRow

End Sub
```